# Unable to open file downloaded via spring rest api

Tags: spring-boot, file

I am writing a service to provide upload/download api for file. I save the file as UIID on the disk while uploading and then use the uiid to download the file via download api. Everything works file for text files but as soon as i try to download image or pdf, i am unable to open it says "unable to open file"? Is there a neccesary encoding to provided?

```
    MediaType contentType = fileProperties.getContentType() == null ? MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM : MediaType.parseMediaType(fileProperties.getContentType());

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(contentType)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileProperties.getOriginalFileName())
            .body(fileProperties.getResource());

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I am able to download the file succesfully there is no error while doing that. Only thing is I can't open the pdf's and images which get's downloaded.

Comment: It turns out this is something because of bug in swagger-ui.